# Rails: Testing the on_create callback only once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec

I have two controllers that create a user, and on creation, I want to send them an email. Because of DRY, I moved the email logic to an `on_create` callback. However, now, every time I create a user in my rspec tests (e.g. with factorygirl), it will send an email.

Some possible ideas I've had:

- I could mock out this behavior, but then I need to mock it all the time...
- I could make it a parameter, (e.g. a boolean that's true only if an email should get sent), but then I'd only add this for the test

What would be the cleanest way of doing this?

Comment: The cleanest way is probably to *not* use model callbacks but to wrap the user creation in a separate class/module/method. There, you can explicitly generate the email (which you then wouldn't do in your tests)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is best practice to invoke the sending of emails from the controllers context, not the models. From the framework's point of view, mailers are very similar to controllers in how they are linked with views and control the flow of action.

I would move the callback logic back into each controller. You are correct it is not strictly [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) but in my opinion this type of scenario it is the most readable and explicit approach, worth the trade.

In your **controller** tests, you can check a mail was delivered:

```
before(:each) { ActionMailer::Base.deliveries = [] }
it "does a thing" do
  subject
  expect(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count).to eq 1
end
```

This approach is future proof should you have to make a change to differentiate these two emails and any developer who picks up the code will not go down a blind alley scratching their head while stray emails go out from them being hidden in the model.